# Camera calibration, how much do intrinsic parameters vary between image sensors

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I'm calibrating a camera/lens using OpenCV's CalibrateCamera. Generally I will recalibrate whenever the lens is touched or removed, or when the focus is adjusted, or with large temperature swings, all of these can affect the intrinsic calibration parameters (ignoring the extrinsic parameters for now which should only change when the camera body is physically moved).

Would you expect intrinsic calibration parameters to change if using the actual same lens with different image sensors? (Assuming the image sensors are the same model).
I know focal length could change as the lens is screwed into the mount of a different image sensor, but what if a kinematic mount of some sort were being used, to ensure consistent mounting?
Is there any reason intrinsic parameters would differ between similar image sensors when using the same physical lens?
I'm going to run some experiments but wondering what the consensus is.

Comment: Check if the centering of the sensor is repeatable. Also sensor orientation. (If I am right, you can't replace the sensor alone, but the whole camera body.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is completely unrelated to programming.

Comment: between sensors of the same model? probably zero, because sensors are semiconductor stuff and fabricated to high specifications. between LENSES? also probably not much, IF they're specified to be the same, and all the movable bits are adjusted similarly.